# How to set the width of a list, in css

Tags: html, css

I have the code, as below. It's a bit annoying to have the text not align (it affects other `li` elements). How can I make it a fixed-width? I've tried width=XYZpx but that did nothing.

```
<li class="date">2/28/2010 9:37:38 AM</li>
...
<li class="date">3/1/2010 9:37:38 AM</li>
```

css

```
li.date
{ 
  background : url(/icons/date.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: In what way does the text not align? Did you assign `width: XYZpx;` to `li.date`? I would think that would work fine for setting the list items to a fixed width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the following (x)html:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="date">List item One</li>
    <li class="date">List item Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The width of the `li` elements can be set by either setting the width of the `div#navigation` (as the `ul` and `li` will default to `display: block` at 100% width + padding + border-widths):

```
div#navigation {width: 200px; }
```

*Or* by setting the width of the `ul`

```
div#navigation > ul {width: 200px; }
```

*Or* by setting the width of the `li` elements themselves:

```
div#navigation > ul > li.date {width: 200px; }
```

I think, unless there was a major typo in your question, that you're trying to assign the width incorrectly, certainly as regards the `width=XYZpx` that you posted. To assign the width this way you should quote the value, so it becomes:

```
...width="XYZpx"...
```

But bear in mind that this is html/xhtml, not css. To set the width with css you should use either:

```
...style="width: 200px;"...
```

If you want to use inline-styles, or, in the stylesheet, use the form (as above):

```
element.selector {width: 200px; }
```

Your comments regarding the text's *alignment* suggests that your `li` elements are perhaps inheriting padding, or a text-indent from somewhere, so you might want to add the styles:

```
div#navigation > ul > li.date {
  text-indent: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. If I've misunderstood your question, or problem, please feel free to drop a comment to my answer, or revise/edit/clarify your question, and I'll try to be more useful.

Comment: I think you understood correctly. Yes i didnt actually write = and use XYZ as my value. I wrote width: 2000px; in my css file as a test with no apparent changes. It appears i cant change the width of one li, i may need to change all or none. I tried using a div inside a li and wrote `li.date div
{
    display: inline;
    border-color: Black;
    color:Red;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    padding 5,5,5,5;
}` The pading and with did nothing (at least in FireFox). This code  originally use a ul i think i should change it to use divs instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the width of the list for the `<ul>` element instead of the `<li>` element. If the list is contained inside of a `<div>`, you could set the width of the `<div>` instead of the `<ul>`, I believe.

```
ul {
   width: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite work through your grammar, but I think all you want is this, right?

```
li.date
{
  background : url(/icons/date.png) no-repeat left top;
  width: 200px; /* or whatever */
}
```