# How to set width for li element of a dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set custom width to the li element of bootstrap dropdown.
I am tried various solutions on stack overflow but none of them worked in my case.

- [CSS list item width/height does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295311/css-list-item-width-height-does-not-work)
- [can we assign width to li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699694/can-we-assign-width-to-li)
- [How to set the width of a list, in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359297/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-list-in-css)
- [How to force div element to keep its contents inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219931/how-to-force-div-element-to-keep-its-contents-inside-container)
  and many more.

The HTML of the dropdown:

```
<span title="Settings" class="dropdown pull-right label label-primary" style="margin-top: 2px;margin-left: -2px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog dropdown-toggle pointer" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="cancel-proj-job" data-href="#">
          <a href="#">Cancel Project Job</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Custom CSS:

```
.jOrgbody div#grid_col_mid .open>ul.dropdown-menu {
   font-size: 8px;
   padding: 0;
}

.jOrgbody div#grid_col_mid ul.dropdown-menu li {
   padding: 0;
}

.jOrgbody div#grid_col_mid ul.dropdown-menu li>a {
   padding: 0;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: issue_image1]
[image: issue_image2]

**Note:**
When I tried to apply fixed width to li. It didn't work.
[image]

Comment: could you please create Jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: @Pirate I will be try to create its jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to do this is as i have done in following code:

```
<span title="Settings" class="dropdown pull-right label label-primary" style="margin-top: 2px;margin-left: -2px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog dropdown-toggle pointer" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="cancel-proj-job" data-href="#" style="width:300px;">
      <a href="#">Cancel Project Job</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

change the "width:300px" to any length you want. Hope this helped.

edit: i have tried it in my browser with 100px and 300px nnd the result is as follows:

[with width:100px;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2OTX.png)
[with width:300px;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSgO9.png)

Comment: I tried to apply fixed width to li but it didn't help.

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer can you add your updated code so i can see it because when i tried it in my browser it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by debugging its css. Basically, the bootstrap has `min-width:160px` set for class `dropdown-menu`. I overwrite this value and `li` element start getting the custom width.